# sort out selected records based on key in unix

Tags: unix, shell, sorting, awk

my input file is like this.

```
01,A,34
01,A,35
01,A,36
01,A,37
02,A,40
02,A,41
02,A,42
02,A,45
```

my output needs to be

```
01,A,37
01,A,36
01,A,35
02,A,45
02,A,42
02,A,41
```

i.e select only top three records (top value based on 3rd column) based on key(1st and 2nd column)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `bash` script to do this provided the data is as shown.

```
pax$ cat infile
01,A,34
01,A,35
01,A,36
01,A,37
02,A,40
02,A,41
02,A,42
02,A,45

pax$ ./go.sh
01,A,37
01,A,36
01,A,35
02,A,45
02,A,42
02,A,41

pax$ cat go.sh
keys=$(sed 's/,[^,]*$/,/' infile | sort -u)
for key in ${keys} ; do
    grep "^${key}" infile | sort -r | head -3
done
```

The first line gets the full set of keys, constructed from the first two fields by removing the final column with `sed` then sorting the output and removing duplicates with `sort`. In this particular case, the keys are `01,A,` and `02,A,`.

It the extracts the relevant data for each key (the `for` loop in conjunction with `grep`), sorting in descending order with `sort -r`, and getting only the first three (for each key) with `head`.

Now, if your key is likely to contain characters special to `grep` such as `.` or `[`, you'll need to watch out.

Comment: hi pax...excellent...ur code is working great...but when i applied the same logic to set of large no. of records,the script hangs out saying no memory...any other alternative???

Comment: @ain: `sed 's/,[^,]*$/,/ infile | sort -u | while read key; do grep "^$key" infile | sort -r | head -3; done`. Note, for large numbers of records, the processing in the `while` loop will be s..l...o....w!

Comment: @aln, it depends on where the problem lies. How many lines in your file (use `wc -l infile`)? How many unique keys (use `sed 's/,[^,]*$/,/' infile | sort -u | wc -l`)?

Comment: @pax:i have around 0.2 million records and keys are around 0.1 million

Answer (score 0):

With *Perl*:

```
perl -F, -lane'
  push @{$_{join ",", @F[0,1]}}, $F[2];
  END {
    for $k (keys %_) {
      print join ",", $k, $_
        for (sort { $b <=> $a } @{$_{$k}})[0..2]
      } 
    }' infile
```

Comment: oh great radoulov....thank u...but could i get the same in awk or in sed taking care of more records also???

Comment: You may try something like this: `sort -t, -k1,2 -k3nr infile | awk -F, '_[$1,$2]++ < 3'`